# Design an algorithm that minimises the load on the most heavily loaded server

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

Reading the book of Aziz & Prakash 2021 I am a bit stuck on problem 3.7 and the associated solution for which I am trying to implement.

The problem says :

> You have n users with unique hashes h1 through hn and
> m servers, numbered 1 to m. User i has Bi bytes to store. You need to
> find numbers K1 through Km such that all users with hashes between
> Kj and Kj+1 get assigned to server j. Design an algorithm to find the
> numbers K 1 through Km that minimizes the load on the most heavily
> loaded server.

The solution says:

> Let L(a,b) be the maximum load on a server when
> users with hash h1 through ha are assigned to servers S1 through Sb in
> an optimal way so that the max load is minimised. We observe the
> following recurrence:

[image]

> In other words, we find the right value of x such that if we pack the
> first x users in b - 1 servers and the remaining in the last servers the max
> load on a given server is minimized.
> Using this relationship, we can tabulate the values of L till we get
> L(n,m). While computing L(a,b) when the values of L is tabulated
> for all lower values of a and b we need to find the right value of x to
> minimize the load. As we increase x, L(x,b-1) in the above expression increases the the sum term decreases. We can do binary search for x to find x that minimises their max.

I know that we can probably use some sort of dynamic programming, but how could we possibly implement this idea into a code?

Comment: The constraints look so heavy, you can just use a greedy algorithm. No need for anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic programming algorithm is defined fairly well given that formula: Implementing a top-down DP algorithm just needs you to loop from `x = 1 to a` and record which one minimizes that `max(L(x,b-1), sum(B_i))` expression.

There is, however, a simpler (and faster) greedy/binary search algorithm for this problem that you should consider, which goes like this:

1. Compute prefix sums for B
2. Find the minimum value of L such that we can partition B into m contiguous subarrays whose maximum sum is equal to L.

   - We know 1 <= L <= sum(B). So, perform a binary search to find L, with a helper function `canSplit(v)` that tests whether we can split B into such subarrays of sum <= `v`.
   - `canSplit(v)` works greedily: Remove as many elements from the start of B as possible so that our sum does not exceed `v`. Repeat this a total of m times; return True if we've used all of B.
   - You can use the prefix sums to run `canSplit` in `O(m log n)` time, with an additional inner binary search.
3. Given L, use the same strategy as the canSplit function to determine the m-1 partition points; find the m partition boundaries from there.